# Get black screen shot when running screen shot on socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-imaging-library

### Model

TRIGGER -> TRIGGER COLLECTOR -> RUN SCREENSHOT

---

**TRIGGER**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket() 

port = 12344
s.connect(('10.35.145.133', port))
s.close()
```

**TRIGGER COLLECTOR**

```
import os
import socket
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("cmd.exe /c python E:\\C\\screenshot.py") #........I say this is called "A"
    s = socket.socket()
    port = 12344
    s.bind(('', port))
    s.listen(1)
    print("Listening")
    while True:
        try:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            print("Accept")
            # CMD run
            os.system("cmd.exe /c python E:\\C\\screenshot.py") #........And this is called "B"
            c.close()
        except BaseException:
            pass
    s.close()
```

**RUN SCREENSHOT**

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

im= ImageGrab.grab()
im.save("image.png", "PNG")
```

---

My model consists of:

1. **Trigger** (This is on Server PC)
2. **Trigger** Collector (This is on Client PC)
3. **Run Screenshot** (This is on Client PC)

---

**1. Trigger**

When a button from Server is clicked, `Trigger` will run and will be triggering `Trigger Collector`.

**2. Trigger Collector**

This script will run on Client and will be waiting for the server to trigger this.

**3. Run Screenshot**

This script will be triggered by `Trigger Collector` and get the screenshot.

---

**Problem:**

See my `Trigger Collector`'s code, I have named my `os.system()` "A" and "B"

1. When A is called:
   The image I got is a Client's Screen
2. When B is called:
   The image I got is a Black Screen

I need to send a screen shot at "B" not at "A", but it doesn't seem to work.

(The reason I put "A" and "B" in the first place is that I want to know the problem, now that I know even the placement of "A" and "B" matters, I know that this is a `socket` problem)

So how do I get 'the correct' screenshot when I run the script at "B"?
**Reminder**: "A" is only a debugging process.

---

**Current solution that I have:**

1. I created a thread at "A", and keep screenshot-ing while "B" will
   save the image when the trigger is up. (This solution will need to
   combine `Trigger Collector` and `Run Screenshot` in one script)

   **The disadvantage of this technique**: This will eat up a lot of resources because I will always take screenshots even when I don't
   need to

EDIT: Responding to my own solution, actually I can use semaphore to make it run synchronized and not wasting any resources :) I think this should end this case.

---

NOTES: If some of you can help and my explanation is not clear enough, feel free to ask me, thank you :)